# Linq ordering both parent and child related entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, hierarchy

I have a parent child model where I want to sort by the SortOrder column of both entities. I have the query working but it seems overly verbose and I was wondering if there was a simpler solution to this problem.

I am initially loading the results into an anonymous type (as you can not load complex types directly into the entity framework entities) then querying that type again to load into the entities. I know I could simplify this by implementing a DTO but was interested in a cleaner solution for this use case.

**Model**

[image]

**Query**

```
public List<Group> GetStaticMeasures(int businessUnitID)
{

    var groups = (from g in ctx.Groups.Where(w => w.BusinessUnitID.Equals(businessUnitID)).OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = g.ID,
                     BusinessUnitID = g.BusinessUnitID,
                     Name = g.Name,
                     SortOrder = g.SortOrder,
                     Datapoints = (from d in ctx.Datapoints where g.ID.Equals(d.StaticGroupID) orderby d.SortOrder select d).ToList()
                 }).ToList();

    var results = from g in groups
                  select new Group
                  {
                      ID = g.ID,
                      BusinessUnitID = g.BusinessUnitID,
                      Name = g.Name,
                      SortOrder = g.SortOrder,
                      Datapoints = g.Datapoints
                  };

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
public IEnumerable<Group> GetStaticMeasures(int businessUnitID)
{
    var groups = ctx.Groups
                   .Include("Datapoints")
                   .Where(w => w.BusinessUnitID.Equals(businessUnitID))
                   .OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder);

    foreach(var g in groups)
    {
       g.Datapoints = g.Datapoints.OrderBy(d => d.SortOrder).ToList();
       yield return g;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its does not compile on the yield line as the type of g in not an iterator type

Comment: @PhilMurray Yes, I changed the signature of the function to `IEnumerable<Group>` but if you need to keep it as a list, create a new list and add the values to that in the loop.